# How to assert a default value of a property with FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, default, fluent-assertions

I have a class with some fields/properties etc., of various types:

```
public string SomeStringData;
public int? SomeNullableIntegerData;
public SomeDataClass SomeSpecificData;
public int SomeIntegerData;
```

In part of my code, only the `SomeStringData` should be filled, and I want to test explicitly that. I use [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions) and have

```
actual.SomeStringData.Should().Be("Whatever");
```

But how to test, that none of the other elements are not touched and still have their default value? I could, of course:

```
actual.SomeNullableIntegerData.Should().NotHaveValue("Must have no value.");
actual.SomeDataClass.Should().BeNull("Must have no value.");
actual.SomeNullableIntegerData.Should().Be(0, "Must have no value.");
```

**But, how to express more clearly that these items should have the default value?**

Like for example with an imaginary `BeDefault` operator:

```
actual.SomeNullableIntegerData.Should().BeDefault("Must have no value.");
actual.SomeDataClass.Should().BeDefault("Must have no value.");
actual.SomeNullableIntegerData.Should().BeDefault("Must have no value.");
```

Are there such options?

Comment: I am late to the party but it would be reasonable to suggest this as an enhancement to the project on GitHub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create extension method

```
public static void ShouldHaveDefaultValue<T>(this T value)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T)))
        throw new AssertionException("Must have default value.");
}
```

Usage:

```
actual.SomeNullableIntegerData.ShouldHaveDefaultValue();
actual.SomeDataClass.ShouldHaveDefaultValue();
actual.SomeIntegerData.ShouldHaveDefaultValue();
```

Extending `Should()` with `BeDefault()` would be difficult, because there is different `Should()` extensions which return different assertions objects - `BooleanAssertions`, `StringAssertions`, `GuidAssertions` etc. And all this assertions classes don't have common base class you would be able to extent.

Comment: Nice, I am going to try this. However, I hoped that there is some already built-in way of doing this. Isn't testing for default values very common, or does this only happen to me?

Comment: @Marcel actually testing for devault values is not common. Usually you should check that value change is occured. That's like football game commenting: *"player A has a ball, player B don't has a ball, player C don't has a ball, player D don't has a ball. Now player A passes ball to player B. Player B has a ball, player A don't has a ball, player C don't has a ball.. etc"* It would be nice to get more information about code you are testing. If only SomeStringData should be filled, then probably it's better to return just string value instead of passing whole object

Comment: You are right about just passing the one value in general. However, in my case the business decision was to always return the same fully fleged object, but filled only with data according to the user's role. Now I want to assert, that for certain roles, only certain data is returned.

Comment: @Marcel well, consider also to return something like dictionary. Its easy to assert returned entries count and check their values. Fill those dictionaries with data according to user's role. You also can create custom dictionary. I would not suggest to use partially-filled classes

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Actually, all those assertion classes do share a common base-class. It's the `ReferenceTypeAssertions` class (although I'm quite sure I'm going to rename it in v3.0).

Comment: @DennisDoomen strange... I see that neither of them share base class. Are you sure value type (int, Guid, boolean etc) assertions share `ReferenceTypeAssertions` base class? Btw creating base assertions class is a good idea for extending functionality in future

Comment: What version of Fluent Assertions are you using?

Comment: @DennisDoomen I use version 2.0.1, for .NET 3.5. I can update, but must stay on .NET 3.5 for the moment.

Comment: @DennisDoomen I used sources available at https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions

Comment: v2.2 still supports .NET 3.5 and uses a common base-class. v3.0 will be .NET 4.0 and higher only (because it uses a PCL).

Answer (score 0):

I would just capture the previous values upfront and assert that after executing whatever is supposed to make the change, those values still have their default values. That proposed `BeDefault` method can never make any assumptions about a 'default'.

Comment: It can, because by default I mean really the default value of that type, for instance 0 (zero) for an integer.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood you. I thought you meant it should have its original value. In that case, BeDefault() does make sense. If you want, you can propose this on GitHub so that I can include it in v3.0.